# OpenCV inverse warpPolar output out of frame

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, transformation, polar-coordinates

When I try to make an inverse polar transformation to my image, the output is outside of the output image. There are also some weird white patterns on the top. I tried to make the output image larger but the circle is on the left side so it didn't help.

I am trying to make a line circle using warpPolar function, for that first I'm flipping the line and giving it a black area as shown on the image, then using the cv2.warpPolar function with WARP_INVERSE_MAP flag.

How can I fully draw the circle, and get its bounding box is my question.

```
line = np.ones(shape=(20,475),dtype=np.uint8)*255

flipped = cv2.rotate(line,cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
cv2.imshow('flipped',flipped)

h,w = flipped.shape

radius = int(h / (2*np.pi)) 

new_image = np.zeros(shape=(h,radius+w),dtype=np.uint8)
h2,w2 = new_image.shape

new_image[: ,w2-w:w2] = flipped
cv2.imshow('polar',new_image)

h,w = new_image.shape

center = (w/2,h) 

output= cv2.warpPolar(new_image,center=center,maxRadius=radius,dsize=(1500,1500),flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP + cv2.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR)

cv2.imshow('output',output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: transformation images]

Comment: What do you mean by saying "get its bounding box is my question" ? What is bounding box you defining ? When i tried your code result is not like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:** I am not getting the same result as you showed above when I tried the same code. You may miss some code lines to add ?*

If I didn't misunderstand your problem,you are trying to get this result: (If I am wrong, I will update the answer accordingly)

[image]

The only point you are  missing is that defining the center and radius. You are making inverse transform here, the input is created by you not `warpPolar`. Since you are defining size as (1500,1500), you need to update center and radius accordingly. Here is my code giving this result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


line = np.ones(shape=(20,475),dtype=np.uint8)*255

flipped = cv2.rotate(line,cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
cv2.imshow('flipped',flipped)

h,w = flipped.shape

radius = int(h / (2*np.pi)) 

new_image = np.zeros(shape=(h,radius+w),dtype=np.uint8)
h2,w2 = new_image.shape

new_image[: ,w2-w:w2] = flipped
cv2.imshow('polar',new_image)

h,w = new_image.shape

center = (750,750) 


maxRadius = 750



output= cv2.warpPolar(new_image,center=center,maxRadius=radius,dsize=(1500,1500),flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP + cv2.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR)

cv2.imshow('output',output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I was trying to get this result I got it after a week posting this but forgot to update, but this solution is correct thanks!  and the upper part was a opencv building issue